# Cannot store command to variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, command, sox

I have been trying to write a program that will take the volume adjustment stat in [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net), and store it in a variable.

To do this you have to do

`sox *your-audio-file* -n stat`,

and the final line will show the stat that I want.

However, when I try to store the whole output of that command in the variable INITSTAT, it remains blank, and the line of code that should be storing the output in the variable is just printing the output to the terminal. This is what I have:

```
INITSTAT=`sox $audioFilePath -n stat`
echo $INITSTAT
```

Where "$audioFilePath" is the path to the audio file I am trying to get the information about.

If anybody knows what is wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So `sox $audioFilePath -n stat` on it's own executes as expected? As a side note, you can wrap `$audioFilePath` with `"`, to avoid issues in case a path contains spaces.

Comment: Try this `INITSTAT=$(sox "$audioFilePath" -n stat)` and let us know if it works.

Comment: From Sox manual on `stat`, "The information is output to the ‘standard error’ (stderr) stream", http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

Comment: @zois yes, `sox $audioFilePath -n stat` will work on its own. How would I be able to store the stderr in a variable? *EDIT* I was able to get it to work with `INITSTAT=$((sox $audioFilePath -n stat) 2>&1)`, hooray! thanks for telling me about the stderr thing.

Comment: @user1984 it doesn't work, it has the same output. I think that's because they are both ways of storing commands in a variable

Comment: The inner parentheses are not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
INITSTAT=$(sox "$audioFilePath" -n stat 2>&1)
```